# Blacklist specific bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, blacklist

While I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, the neighbor (apparently) bought a "Hue Lamp" which appears in the list of bluetooth devices on my machine.

Tried using boolean Blocked [rw] setting of [bt-device](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bt-device.1.html) set to true, which works for a while, then the "Hue Lamp" reappears.

Is there any way to tell the Settings manager to *not* list this device?

**Edit:** I specifically mean the "Bluetooth" tab of the graphical settings manager, see the picture.[image]

Comment: Those devices are simply whatever devices `bluez` knows about, so it's very possible that a second lamp appeared in range, rather than being the same one. You likely also need to block it as well. You can use `bluetoothctl` to get a lower level view of what devices are visible, as well as the `blocked` and other properties on them.

Comment: @dobey Hmm, blocking using `bluetoothctl` didnt' have any effect on the settings manager. But now I know that `bluez` is working behind the scenes - thanks for the hint!